# Realm: Creating Observable from asynchronous Transaction

Tags: android, asynchronous, realm, rx-java

In my Android app, I am using Realm and RxJava, and I want to update an Object by passing a new value. I use `realm.executeTransactionAsync()` for that. But I would like to subscribe to this event to do error handling in the class where I use this method. What I have done so far is this:

```
public Observable updateDogAge(final String dogId, final int age) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Dog>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Dog> subscriber) {
            realm.executeTransactionAsync(realm1 -> realm1.where(Dog.class)
                            .equalTo(DOG_ID_FIELD, dogId)
                            .findFirst()
                            .setAge(age),
                    subscriber::onCompleted,
                    subscriber::onError);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I would like to get a boolean flag of whether or not updating this object was successful. Right now I feel like just calling `subscriber::onCompleted` is not the right solution. I am also not sure about the use of `Observable.onCreate()`.

Can you tell me what is the right way to get an Observable (or Single) from an asynchronous Realm transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend *creating your own "asynchronous" transaction* for RxJava support.

```
public Observable updateDogAge(final String dogId, final int age) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            r.executeTransaction((realm) -> realm.where(Dog.class)
                        .equalTo(DOG_ID_FIELD, dogId)
                        .findFirst()
                        .setAge(age));
            return Observable.just(true);
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
        }
    });
}
```

*Note*: my RxJava is a bit hazy, I don't use it regularly.

---

And of course, you need to subscribe this on a scheduler that runs on background threads.

```
updateDogAge(id, age).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())./*...*/
```

---

---

In fact, I think you can use `Observable.fromCallable()` instead:

```
public Observable updateDogAge(final String dogId, final int age) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            r.executeTransaction((realm) -> realm.where(Dog.class)
                        .equalTo(DOG_ID_FIELD, dogId)
                        .findFirst()
                        .setAge(age));
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That looks nice and simple, but the try-catch is not catching the Throwable in the transaction. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: What do you mean `catching the throwable in the transaction`? The `executeTransaction()` already cancels the transaction on exception, that is what it is for.

Comment: I was trying to use it with `executeTransactionAsync`. With synchronous transaction it works.

Comment: One thing though, Realm is now giving me the message: `REALM: Mixing asynchronous queries with local writes should be avoided. Realm will convert any async queries to synchronous in order to remain consistent. Use asynchronous writes instead.` Should I just ignore it?

Comment: No, you should apply `.subscibeOn(Schedulers.io())` to `updateDogAge` when you call it

Answer (score 1):

I created Completable for RxJava2

```
fun dbTransaction(db: Realm, transaction: Realm.Transaction): Completable {
    return Completable.create { emitter ->
        db.executeTransactionAsync(transaction, Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess { emitter.onComplete() }, Realm.Transaction.OnError { emitter.onError(it) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case when operation complete successful, you need true, and if erro occur, you need false, right? Try to return true always and add .onnErrorReturn, returning false.
You can do asynchronous transaction by yourself by using .subscribeOn() and .observeOn() methods and synchronous realm transaction. But, by doing so, you need to get and release Realm instance every time, because it is Thread- dependent. This will be a bit easier, because you'll return true and false expliitly depending on operations success.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Can you show me some code example for that?

Comment: that is what in answer below, wrapped in .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

Comment: and with .onErrorReturn(false) operator

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following, in order to use **executeTransactionAsync** instead of plain **executeTransaction**:

```
return Observable.fromEmitter(emitter -> {
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(bgRealm -> {
            bgRealm.where(Dog.class)
                   .equalTo(DOG_ID_FIELD, dogId)
                   .findFirst()
                   .setAge(age));
            emitter.onNext(true);
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        emitter.onError(e);
    }
}, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```

That way all your Realm transactions will be asynchronous and you will get rid of all the warnings about *"Mixing asynchronous queries with local writes..."*.

A possible downside of this approach is that **fromEmitter** only works in later versions of RxJava 1.x and it is still experimental at this time (RxJava 1.2.3). Not sure if there is an equivalent approach for RxJava 2.